# Is it possible to change $SystemCharacterEncoding?

Tags: front-end, export, output-formatting, notebooks, formatting

In my machine I get

[image]

Now let's check the official CP949 map.

http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP949.TXT

...
...
[image]
...
...

The code point of ♥ in **CP949** is 2665.
(The code point of ♥ in **Unicode** is A2BE.)

Below is a screenshot of mathematica help about `$SystemCharacterEncoding` :

[image]

The value of `$SystemCharacterEncoding` is `UTF-8`, it is different from the value of my machine.

Seems `UTF-8` is the default, then why my machine produced `CP949` ?

Is it possible to change the value of `$SystemCharacterEncoding` so that

the output of `"♥"//FullForm` becomes different from `\:2665` ?

Can I change the value of `$SystemCharacterEncoding` to `UTF-8` ?

To Syed : Thank you, what I get is

[image]

Comment: See what you get: `({ToString["♥", 
      CharacterEncoding -> #], #} & /@ $CharacterEncodings) // 
 Multicolumn[#, 4] &` . My encoding is WindowsANSI

Comment: Thank you, I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can change that by assigning the value.

But I think you don't need that, as you may get it wrong:

> #        Column #1 is the cp949 code (in hex)
> #        Column #2 is the Unicode (in hex as 0xXXXX)
> #        Column #3 is the Unicode name (follows a comment sign, '#')